# Azure App registration: Automate the process of SSO user linking

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, registration

We are building a platform, where Azure AD user accounts will be used as SSO user for all applications. There is this one application (our main ERP system, 3rd party), which has internal users and can link a SSO login from an openid provider to those users.

Is there a way to automate this linking process on our side by code without the user manually generating the link? We want to avoid the users trying to link any other non-related MS account they have registered (3000 external users) to the main application login, because this will fail since we only allow single tenant. What we know so far:

- We use Azure Functions to code all the processes
- We have an API endpoint to the ERP to create the SSO link, but since there seems to be no way of getting the user subject id from the Azure application registration, this looks like a dead end
- Is there a way to impersonate the user in Azure functions and create the link?
- B2C is no option since we want to assign licenses (university context)

Any other ways, we could potentially solve this?

Thanks for your ideas and have a sunny day!

Best
Christian

Comment: looks like the subject id is available after all, we found it using this post as a starting help: [link](https://jd-bots.com/2021/07/18/how-to-get-azure-id-token-using-postman/)

Answer (score 0):

https://jd-bots.com/2021/07/18/how-to-get-azure-id-token-using-postman/ - using the info here, we managed to get idtoken from postman and implemented the same via Azure functions, the subject id is available in the id token

As requested a summary of the link:

1. Download Postman
2. Service Principal in Azure – To know how to create a service principal, go through my post on Creating Service Principal using PowerShell.
3. The user trying to get the id_token should not have enabled the Multifactor Authentication.
4. Add API permission: Microsoft Graph Delegate

   - offline_access
   - openid
   - profile
   - User.Read [Present under User dropdown]
5. Click on Add permission and ask your Admin to Grant the Admin consent (or do it yourself, if you are admin).

Launch Postman and create the following request, replacing tenantId with your ID:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenantId}}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

In the body, add the following values:

```
client_id – {{clientId}}
scope – user.read openid profile offline_access
client_secret – {{clientSecret}}
username – your_username@your_company.com
password – the user’s password
grant_type – password
```

Click on Send and see the response. It contains both access_token and id_token.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. **Can you [edit] your answer to summarize the relevant guidance from the link?** Answers on Stack Overflow can certainly link to additional information, but they should stand on their own even if the page they are linking to is later (re)moved. This is important because often, over time, the linked pages are no longer available, which is frustrating for future members of the community.